# How do i hide files/folders in a zip file?

Tags: filesystems, hidden-files

i am creating this 'cicada 3301' style puzzle and i want the game to start from a zip folder with some visible files that are the start to the puzzle and then some hidden files that you should go back and access at a later point. How do i accomplish such a task?

I have searched around on google but havent been able to find much